# Alternate method to AllowOverride all in Apache

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

Is there any other option to `AllowOverride all`  except edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`, means I have more than `two projects` in my remote server when I edit default to `AllowOverride all` my 2nd project stops working and when I edit default to `AllowOverride none` vice versa.

I want to run both projects at the same time

Here is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may specify AllowOverride for each folder of your two applications

```
<Directory /project1>
AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /project2>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: It seems ok. You may try a graceful command to check for errors first. Please let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: you placed the Directory directives in some virtual host that will never match. You may place the directives in the main apache configuration not in the virtualhost configuration, you you may specify the servername in the virtual host directive so your applications will actually be in a virtualhost.

Comment: :) there ? I want to ask something

Comment: :) this way is gud to access two project1 and project2 but if have more than 10-11 projects then? any alternate method to keep those 10th projects AllowOverride None while except 11th projects are AllowOverride All, because daily i create new project in my www folder so i do not want to change my default page again n again